# Galaxy Tab P7500 won't boot

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-10, unbricking

I was trying to install a custom ROM from recovery menu, but it failed and now my tablet stuck on Samsung Logo and won't boot. In recovery menu I get these errors:

```
E:failed to mount /system (Invalid argument)
E:install_application_for_customer:Can't mount /system
```

in 'apply update from/ sdcard' menu, I face an empty list, which means the sdcard is not mounted.

What should I do to survive my tablet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, the only option you've: Flash ROM over USB using Odin (if you have Windows PC). You can find firmware files for your device on Internet (look XDA Forum).

Comment: Thanks so much, I did that, and It worked. I added the link to your post.